# Database Design for Billing System application

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design

i am doing small billing application,
i need some guidance about  database design for billing software,
i have product table in this am maintaining below fields,

Product table

```
Product code , unique , 
quantity ,
price,
vat,
discount ,
```

and some of few columns like userid, createddate ,

Basket table,

```
basketid ,
PHPSESSIONID ,
productcode,
quantity ,
```

and few required details like userid, created date ,
counter people entering bills are initially store into tblbasket table,
when billing is confirmed , Required details are move to tblSale table,

tblSale table:

```
id AI,PK,
BasketSessionID ,(no foreign key concept but just inserting that tbl basket PHPSESSIONID ) 
productcose , and few required details,
```

The above details am holding for billing application,

Now i need some guidence to proceed furtheir,

1. need to implement reports , daily sale, returns and every thing,

So First step is,

i want to maintain something like below,

1. Product code Total stockin count,
2. after sold need some stock out count,
3. if returns means how to maintain,

So totally i want table design for Stockin, Stockout,Returns , Free CD,

Total idea behind is,
Reporting view for billing application,

Comment: A little formatting would go a long way

Comment: @Bharanikumar, I agree with BenV, I have done some rudimentary formatting of your text, but please, click the edit button and fix capital letters, no space before comma, etc. Sentences ending with . not ,

Comment: I would suggest you design schema to have accounts separate to users and transactions between two accounts.

Comment: this intranet application for small CD selling shop, So only two booth for sale , so at present only one user that user name is sale

Comment: I would also suggest setting some standards to follow for the DB. It will make it more readable. For example you use basketid and PHPSESSIONID. I would pick one and make it more readable: basket_id, php_session_id OR BasketID, PhpSessionID, etc.

Comment: for example , i said PHPSESSIONID, but actually in implementation in my table design my field name is BasketSessionID

Comment: youre also asking for problems if you mix case ofthe characters. Dont use camel case... jsut use underscore as a word separator, then if you need to convert it in your app write a general purpose inflector class/function to convert back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

Before you make your final decisions on the database schema take some time to look at the Microsoft example data AdventureWorks2008 for SQL Server.

- This [link](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/) points to the availabel samples for SQL Server
- This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff487370.aspx) is a tutorial on creating reports.
- This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296196%28SQL.90%29.aspx) is a sample web app for Adventure Works

After you have reviewed the database design I believe you will have the answers to your questions mentioned above.  If you have additional questions you can reference the AdventureWorks databse to help describe your question or goal.